# Where date is current or over

Tags: php, mysql

How can say it should NOT take the rows that has "expired" the date?

```
select * from campaigns where slut =< CURRENT_DATE() ?
```

Comment: What is your table definition?

Comment: "slut" is DATE format, ex. 2013-05-01

Comment: What's the problem with the query you tried?

Comment: Where is the "expired" field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from campaigns where slut >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

Selects all rows where 'slut' is above or equal to current date

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator `=<` in MySQL. Use `<=` or `>=` instead, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You asked "**rows that has "expired" the date?**"

and you are queried for getting record that are not expired.

so use `>=` instead of `<=` even `=<` is wrong its should be `<=`